# MySQL concat year month date colums to date column in same table

Tags: mysql, concatenation, str-to-date

I have a table 'setlists' in mysql with columns 'year' 'month' 'day' of int type that I would like to str_to_date and concat into a new column 'date' in the same table. This is what I have so far but I cant seem to get the syntax right. It wont run. I have already created the new date column and set it as date type.

```
UPDATE setlists
SET date = str_to_date(concat(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%Y-%m-%d') FROM setlists
```

Data:

I am trying to concat the year month day columns into the date column of the same table.

```
date  year  month  day
null  2018  01     01
null  2017  01     01
```

The current error output is as follows:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM setlists' at line 2

Comment: Year month and day are mysql date functions. Try enclosing them in backticks `.

Comment: `It won't run`. What is the output of your query? Do you see errors? If so, post them in your question.

Comment: Please show us some data.  @P.Salmon year, month, and day are not reserved keywords.

Comment: those are the names of the columns in the setlists table, am I not able to concat columns from a table?

Comment: You must check the syntex of update

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `FROM setlists` at the end of your update query.  It does not belong there.

```
UPDATE setlists
SET date = str_to_date(concat(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

SQL update syntax is such that the target table is specified as whatever follows `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfect.  Of course it was something obvious...haha

Answer (score 1):

With update queries you should not use the `FROM [table]`, unless you use a `SELECT` query for input, you already define which table you want to update with `UPDATE setlists`.

Remove the `FROM setlists` from your query to make it work.

See the [UPDATE query syntax documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

So:

```
UPDATE setlists
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

See: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3e60d/1)

Comment: Updated my answer, I agree that you should write standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

There's a neater way:

```
DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', year, month, day))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the usage of year,month,day functions

```
   UPDATE setlists
    SET date = str_to_date(concat(year(sysdate()),'-',month(sysdate()),'-',day(sysdate())), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

If these are columns then

```
UPDATE setlists
SET date = str_to_date(concat(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%Y-%m-%d');
```